# Angular parse string to scope object

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

If I have a string with value 'order.buyer.address.street' and there exists an order object on the scope, how do I get to the address object?

I mean, is there an angular function (such as $parse,...) that can be used to get to the address object?

I know I could split the string and iterate to the object, but I want to know if there is an easier way to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use `$scope.$eval`:

```
var address = $scope.$eval('order.buyer.address');
```

Answer (score 1):

Well $parse can indeed be used to pull out the address object, as long as the hierarchy is maintained.

```
var getter = $parse('buyer.address');
var context = order;
var address = getter(context);
```

Comment: I want to parse the full string, as zeroflagL does. I guess I can do var address = $scope.$parse('order.buyer.address')($scope);  => What is best to use? the $eval(..) or $parse(...)($scope) ?

Comment: Eval can only be used on scope object, If the object is on $scope then $scope.$eval also works